# Trying to connect to Hadoop Cluster using Talend

Tags: hadoop, talend

I have:

Cloudera quickstart VM 5.8
Talend 5.4.1

I have entered the following credentials:

Manager URI(with port)   http://quickstart.cloudera:7180/
username                 cloudera
password                 cloudera

I get the error message " Connection failed, please check the connection 
parameters."

How do i fix this issue?

Comment: Try using the IP rather than `quickstart.cloudera`, which is not accessible from Windows unless you've updated your hosts entries

Comment: already tried. still the same issue. Below are my Cloudera VM details:

Comment: [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ ifconfig
eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:1D:54:38  
          inet addr:192.168.26.134  Bcast:192.168.26.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:443 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:394 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:63424 (61.9 KiB)  TX bytes:317305 (309.8 KiB)

Comment: lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:9356 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9356 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1503495 (1.4 MiB)  TX bytes:1503495 (1.4 MiB)

[cloudera@quickstart ~]$

Comment: The VM ip being `192.168.26.134`? Please edit your question rather than put it in the comments.

Comment: Issue is resolved. I have used the IP address instead of quickstart.cloudera. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`quickstart.cloudera` is only in the VM itself.

Use the IP of the VM from the host machine.

Comment: FYI Talend can connect to Cloudera Manager (or Ambari) to "sniff" Hadoop configuration properties via their specific REST API -- including NameNode address, RM address, etc -- i.e. no need to copy all `*-site.xml` files to the Talend server. It works, in simple cases (e.g. Kerberos authentication requires badly documented tweaks anyway).

Comment: Hi Cricket, I  was following the instructions from the following URL:                     http://synchronicanalytics.com/connecting-talend-open-studio-to-cloudera-quickstart/                                                                                                           I hope this clarifies what i was trying. I can ping my Windows IP from Cloudera VM & vice versa. not sure what went wrong.

Comment: @Ravi, try using the IP rather than `quickstart.cloudera`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue creating a Hadoop Cluster connection in Talend, to resolve it I did the following.

Create a Bridged Adaptor for your VM under Network, this will allow your host machine to communicate with the VM.

https://www.linuxbabe.com/virtualbox/a-pretty-good-introduction-to-virtualbox-bridged-networking-mode

Then when you have set this up check the IP of the VM (ifconfig command) it is likely not to be the 10. range but the IP of the second connection, on mine it is the one labelled eth1. My IP for this was a 192.168. IP range.

This worked for me and I managed to create a connection including a hive connection successfully.